# typescript, can not handle union of missing property. [tsserver 2339] Property 'data' does not exist on type

Tags: typescript

I have two Objects, one has property data and the other one has not:

```js
const jsonWithNoData = {}
const jsonWithData = { data: [1, 2, 3] }
```

After taking the union, I am trying to perform a type narrowing:

```js
const jsonWithNoData = {}
const jsonWithData = { data: [1, 2, 3] }

type JsonWithNoData = typeof jsonWithNoData
type JsonWithData = typeof jsonWithData

type JsonData = JsonWithNoData | JsonWithData // <--- union here

function foo(arg:JsonData) {
  if (arg && arg.data) {
    //           ^^^^<-------[tsserver 2339] Property 'data' does not exist on type 'JsonData'.
    return arg.data
    //         ^^^^<---------[tsserver 2339] Property 'data' does not exist on type 'JsonData'.
  } else {
    return 'no data'
  }
}

console.log(foo({}))
```

I am receiving an error say: [tsserver 2339] Property 'data' does not exist on type 'JsonData'
But why? isn't union means jsonWithNoData OR jsonWithData ? if so how come my type guard is not legit ?

the above snippet can be found [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=19&ssc=21&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAVhcB1AllAFgORAEQIZR4wC8MA3gL4CwAUKJLAsmuvoSeTACYF4BcMANoBGADQwATOIDMAXRjUatKAE8ADgFMYAKURhUGbGyKlVmkADN4eg1ly9l6rbuYZjHMxsvXXrB0ppPHT13Uhd9FiNeGAAfYN93AHpEmAAeAFpMmABXMBRwGHQNACcNWloLXOAofLAYCxAQAAo8YoBzPnDjAEpyWhgYFCsW9pgAMjGYVraAOh5CXrJ+gZhklfX1gD1tzYzM-fTBKAgIEoA3EslpaQBOeQAFYpBNYtUYAHJ5vHfuEA0IGBgECwDQADxQ0BgBSC7y6vHeM2WA1KUGyxTq0zm-nWaw2Kx2uwORKOJ3Olwk1zuMEezxKb0+8N+-0BwJgYIhsGhTg+cMICOWFDZABtTn0aOsUWi6u8gdx4QLaIpaPREEKNDMhSA2k0Gs1KN1urQgA)

**Update**:
To illustrate that typescript really **cannot** see the property 'data', and that it is not because of error in my the type-guard logic, I rewrote the above as following:

```js
const jsonWithNoData = {}
const jsonWithData = { data: [1, 2, 3] }

type JsonWithNoData = typeof jsonWithNoData
type JsonWithData = typeof jsonWithData

type JsonData = JsonWithNoData | JsonWithData // <--- union here

function foo(arg:JsonData) {

  const isObject = arg  && (Object.prototype.toString.call(arg) === '[object Object]') 

  if ( isObject && Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(arg, 'data') ) {
    // now we are sure that the property 'data' does exist !! 
    return arg.data
    //         ^^^^<----But we still get error
    //                  [tsserver 2339] Property 'data' does not exist on type 'JsonData'.

  } else {
    return 'no data'
  }
}

console.log(foo({ data: [1, 2, 3] }));
```

You can see the type error still persist.
you can find the update snippet [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=24&ssc=38&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAVhcB1AllAFgORAEQIZR4wC8MA3gL4CwAUKJLAsmuvoSeTACYF4BcMANoBGADQwATOIDMAXRjUatKAE8ADgFMYAKURhUGbGyKlVmkADN4eg1ly9l6rbuYZjHMxsvXXrB0ppPHT13Uhd9FiNeGAAfYN93AHpEmAAeAFpMmABXMBRwGHQNACcNWloLXOAofLAYCxAQAAo8YoBzPnDjAEpycpoYGHpoGBQIAHkAIzgNao5WtsGAMiWYJqmZ6oA6NWKQKH2nLYOAZShilDA2reA8ABs7lvbe4leYAHJBEGnZ2A3f2TvXr9QYoKxNUYTH5zFYwf7bXb7Q6aLboPATADuYAACntNMVVDd7o8FuJ3jxCECYL0yLRBoNkjAwCAMTAMVpWloINlSjAMAQ%20UUYIj8aoPhS8O9uCANBAYBoAB5jWAAQhVMDp9NKUB5dQWWwlmoZKXpppgAD1LeaMpl0gAhbKwdkwaAoB4wNoaWAlPbFI0wRlmoNBwRQCAQEoANxKkmk0gAnPJcSBRSpxbwpVwZXLmd6lSMCkF3l0M1sQQp5XcI30BlqvbqPszuBnNYpFLRhiA7hotncQG0mg1mmRm4QBCJxFIYHIFN1uv1aEA):

Comment: `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call` doesn't do type narrowing, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the condition `arg && arg.data`, the variable `arg` has type `JsonData` and the first part of the condition does not narrow this type; so the expression `arg.data` is accessing a property that `arg` might not have, so `tsc` gives a type error.

Yes, accessing a non-existent property is fine in Javascript, and will just give `undefined`, but the compiler doesn't want to assume that when you access a possibly-non-existent property, you're aware you're doing so and are OK with it being `undefined`. If you wrote the same code thinking `arg.data` is a boolean, number or string property, you might expect the condition to be false because it had a falsey (but not undefined) value. In that case, the compiler would be right to tell you about it, so it has to give the same error in other cases (like this one) too.

You can instead write `arg && 'data' in arg` as the condition; this makes it clear  that you are aware `arg.data` might not exist, and also has the benefit of narrowing the type of `arg` inside the `if` block so that `return arg.data` type-checks:

```js
if(arg && 'data' in arg) {
//        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ no type error

    return arg.data;
    //     ^^^ type narrowed by the `in` operator

}
```

Comment: In the condition `arg && arg.data`, the variable data is not type `JsonData`. It has type  `any`.

Comment: That's a typo - should say "the variable `arg`". I'll fix it, thanks.

Comment: Could you please illustrate what you mean when you said "You can instead write arg && 'data' in arg as the condition"?  Perhaps you can show as a snippet in http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/ ? Thanks.

Comment: Just change the `if` condition from `arg && arg.data` to `arg && 'data' in arg`. [Playground Link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=12&ssc=1&pln=13&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAVhcB1AllAFgORAEQIZR4wC8MA3gL4CwAUKJLAsmuvoSeTACYF4BcMANoBGADQwATOIDMAXRjUatKAE8ADgFMYAKURhUGbGyKlVmkADN4eg1ly9l6rbuYZjHMxsvXXrB0ppPHT13Uhd9FiNeGAAfYN93AHpEmAAeAFpMmABXMBRwGHQNACcNWloLXOAofLAYCxAQAAo8YoBzPnDjAEpyWhgYFCsW9pgAMjGYAHIeQinButa23rJ+gZhSqGzixfaAOlm8NYoYDQAbCC1VmnWNjS2d6bAQbl4p49pFWnpEM409s4gNpNBrNSjdbq0IA)

Comment: Thanks, that was perfect! One last thing, could you please put your code from playground in your answer? or should i do it for you ?